# ng-class-even not applying class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I'm trying to zebra stripe my `ng-repeat` so the rows can be easily distinguished.

I think I have everything wired up correctly, but the classes just aren't being applied.

I've created a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0bNMi8m2p2g8b15oqJUI?p=preview).

My html looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="removal in removals" ng-class-even="even" ng-class-odd="odd" class="remove-relation-titles-list">
      <div class="pull-left relation-titles-left-list">
           <span class="acct-title acct-num">{{removal.AcctType}} {{removal.AcctNo}}</span>
           <span class="acct-title"> - Standard Checking</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

So, the regular class is being applied just fine, but the even and odd ones aren't at all. If you inspect the object and add the `even` class yourself, it shows up beautifully.  I've tried moving this down to the `div` inside the `ng-repeat` with no results.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your ng-class to:-

```
ng-class="{'even':$even,'odd':$odd}"
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/POhMfx?p=preview)**

`$even` and `$odd` are the properties added by ng-repeat on its scope.

or change it to take [string value of the class names](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd) otherwise it will try to replace the class based on the property `even` or `odd` which does not exist:-

```
ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'"
```

Comment: Your first one has the evens and odds wrong, it counts the first one as an even (weird). The second is what I was looking for, thank you :)

Comment: @Bobo yeah thats cos first one actually places even based on the index, first one being 0 indexed... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17" data-require="angular.js@1.0.7"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="removeTitlesCtrl">
      <div id="body_content_wrapper">
        <div>
          <h4 class="heading toggle header-block">These are the accounts chosen</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="removal in removals" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'" class="remove-relation-titles-list">
          <div class="pull-left relation-titles-left-list">
            <span class="acct-title acct-num">{{removal.AcctType}} {{removal.AcctNo}}</span>
            <span class="acct-title"> - Standard Checking</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is a simple mistake please correct.

```
ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'"
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't catch that myself! :)